# Radius of convergence of $\frac{1}{1-z}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be holomorphic function on an open unit disk such that $\lim_{z \to 1} f(z)$ doesn't exists. Let $f(z) = \Sigma_{i=1}^{\infty} a_iz^i$ be its Taylor series around $0$. Then the radius of convergence of $f(z)$ is?

Option

1) $R = 0$

2) $0 < R < 1$

3) $R = 1$

4) $R > 1$.

My attempt:

I considered the function $f(z) = \frac{1}{1 - z} = \Sigma_{i = 0}^{\infty}z^i$. This satisfies the above hypothesis, and its radius of convergence is $R < 1$, hence option 2) is correct. But the answer key says option 4) is correct? So can anyone explain me the reason?

Reference:
CSIR NET DEC 2017 Qno 34, Paper A
http://csirhrdg.res.in/mathA_Dec2017.pdf
http://csirhrdg.res.in/Mathkey_Dec2017.pdf

Comment: Your reference doesn't help much without a link. And I think it should be written "on **the** open unit disk ..."

Comment: The radius of convergence of $\frac{1}{1 - z}$ is ${} = 1$, not $< 1$. – Both (2) and (4) are wrong.

Comment: I agree with Martin. By your simple example the correct option should (3), not (4)...and certainly not (2).

Answer (score 1):

Your apporach is wrong, because the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$ is $1$.

The Taylor series about $a$ of a holomorphic function $f$ always converges on any disk $D(a,r)$ contained in the domain of $f$. Therefore, the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $f$ centered at $0$ is *at least* $1$. If it was greater than one, we would have\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n&=\lim_{z\to1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n\\&=\lim_{z\to1}f(z).\end{align}But this is impossible, since this last limit doesn't exist. Therefore, the radius of convergence is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Given that $f(z)$  be holomorphic function on an open unit disk, so
let $$f(z)=\frac{1}{1-z}$$
then $\quad\lim_{z \to 1} f(z)\quad$ does not exist.

Taylor series of $f(z)$ about $z=0$ is $$f(z)=(1-z)^{-1}=1+z+z^2+z^3+. . . $$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n\qquad \text{where}\quad a_n=1\quad \forall n=0, 1, 2, . . . $$
Radius of convergence $$R=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{1}=1$$

**Only "option $3$" is correct**.